# Google AnalyticsReporting.v4 VS Analytics Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, google-analytics-api

I have system that pulls report data from the Analytics API (Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4.Data.Report) and I'm seeing strange differences between the data returned by that vs the data I see on the actual Analytics website.

For example, on the Analytics website if I check for Organic Sessions for Feb 2019 and March 2019 I might see:

`30,100 for March`

When I query the API I see 30,100 for March if I *only* search for `2019-03-01` to `2019-03-31` in my date range with the following params:

```
var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
{
    DateRanges = new DateRange() {
        StartDate = "2019-03-01",
        EndDate = "2019-03-31"
    },
    Dimensions = new List<Dimension>().Add(new Dimension()
    {
        Name = "ga:yearMonth"
    },
    new Dimension() {
        Name = "ga:segment"
    }),
    Metrics = new List<Metric>().Add(new Metric()
    {
        Expression = "ga:sessions",
        Alias = "Sessions"
    }),
    ViewId = "[MYID]",
    OrderBys = new List<OrderBy>().Add(new OrderBy() {
        FieldName = "ga:yearMonth",
        SortOrder = "ASCENDING"
    });,
    Segments = new List<Segment>().Add(new Segment() {
        SegmentId = "gaid::-5" //organic
    }),
    FiltersExpression = "",
    IncludeEmptyRows = false
};
```

If I extend my date range on the API call to include Feb so: 
`2019-02-01` to `2019-03-31` using the same params, I get an increase in sessions...so something like 30,700 for example.

```
var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
{
    DateRanges = new DateRange() {
        StartDate = "2019-02-01",
        EndDate = "2019-03-31"
    },
    Dimensions = new List<Dimension>().Add(new Dimension()
    {
        Name = "ga:yearMonth"
    },
    new Dimension() {
        Name = "ga:segment"
    }),
    Metrics = new List<Metric>().Add(new Metric()
    {
        Expression = "ga:sessions",
        Alias = "Sessions"
    }),
    ViewId = "[MYID]",
    OrderBys = new List<OrderBy>().Add(new OrderBy() {
        FieldName = "ga:yearMonth",
        SortOrder = "ASCENDING"
    });,
    Segments = new List<Segment>().Add(new Segment() {
        SegmentId = "gaid::-5" //organic
    }),
    FiltersExpression = "",
    IncludeEmptyRows = false
};
```

I'm making a `Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4.Data.ReportRequest`

Comment: You may need a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to figure this one out.  First check the status from the response and see if you are getting 200 OK.  If you are not getting 200 then there is an error occurring.  Then compare the initial request of the data you are getting in the Browser with the application and see if the http header are the same.  The API is probably using the default Browser installed on the PC (like IE) but the website only supports Chrome.  This will be obvious by comparing headers.

Comment: check the responce make sure its says isgolden,  then check the sampling rate. you may be getting sampled data.  Then make sure that you are including all of the dimensions and metrics in the report from the website and the one you are sending to the api.  they must be the same or your analytics will not return the same results.

Comment: @DaImTo it does say `dataIsGolden=true` _but_ I can see values in both the `samplesReadCounts` and `samplingSpaceSizes` on the data returned

Comment: shorten your date range your getting sampled data. Byond that take a screen shot of the actual report you are trying to compare show me the diffrence please

Comment: Ok. I might try and adding multiple 1 month date ranges to the batchget rather than one set spanning N months. Maybe that will help.